# Use Dictionary on Mongo Update without wrapper?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a dictionary and I want to do an upsert but the only way I found is wrapping it into a field with .Set, Is there a way that each dictionary entry is converted to a field?

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Test1", 1 }, { "Test2", 2 } };

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", LoggerScope.Identifier);
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update
     .Set() //
     .SetOnInsert("InsertDate", DateTime.UtcNow);
var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

await _Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this extension method to do the job:

```
    public static UpdateDefinition<TDocument> SetDictionary<TDocument, TKey, TValue>(this UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        foreach (var field in dict)
        {
            update = update.Set(field.Key as String, field.Value);
        }

        return update;
    }
```